# Recursively search root outlook folders for specific folder

Tags: python, recursion, outlook, pywin32, win32com

I'm working on a script that creates a report based on data contained in emails. Below is a quick recursive function I wrote to return the folder object that contains the email with the data.

I use the function twice in the program. One call is able to function normally and lets me get the data I need from the emails in that folder. However, the other appears to return an empty folder because when I call f.getLast() it returns Null.

To make it weirder, if I use a non-recursive implementation and call the function as many times as I need to get to the correct folder, the folder is populated. Is there something I'm missing?

**Relevant Code Block**

```
EMAIL = "user.email@domain.com"
FOLDERNAME = "Test Folder"

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
for folder in outlook.Folders:
   if folder.Name == EMAIL:
      folderRoot = folder

def findFolderRecursive(folderName, directory):
   if directory.Name == folderName:
      return directory
   else:
      for folder in directory.Folders:
         result = findFolderRecursive(folderName, folder)
         if result != None and result.Name == folderName:
            return result

folder = findFolder(FOLDERNAME, folderRoot)
latest = folder.Items.GetLast()
report = latest.Attachments(1)
```

**Error when executing**

```
      1 folder = findFolder(FOLDERNAME, folderRoot)
      2 latest = folder.Items.GetLast()
----> 3 report = latest.Attachments(1)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Attachments'
```

**Non recursive function for reference**

```
def findFolder(folderName, directory):
   for folder in directory:
      if folder.Name == folderName:
          return folder
```

Comment: `findFolderRecursive` is not recursive?

Comment: My bad that function call should be findFolderRecursive, I changed the function name in the post to differentiate them but forgot to update it in the recursive call.

Comment: I lifted your code sample. A few observations: `folderRoot` has to be declared at global scope (at least on my Python 3.7); the folder name is case-sensitive; and I assume the line should read `folder = findFolderRecursive(FOLDERNAME, folderRoot)`. If I change all that, then the code runs and finds one of my sub-folders. I suggest you put in some `print` statements in the recursive function so you can check it is not passing over your target folder.